# Grant all privileges to a database MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying perform this SQL command on MySQL database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON keystone.* TO keystone@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'Password123..';
```

And is throwing this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'Password123..'' at line 1
```

I have this version of MySQL: "mysql  Ver 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))"

I have this configuration:

```
[mysqld]

bind-address = 0.0.0.0
default-storage-engine = innodb
innodb_file_per_table
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
init-connect = 'SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Remove the "IDENTIFIED BY ..." part. That's the syntax for creating users, it is not needed for grant.

Comment: The "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version" is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html, error messages are useful for reading and not just as search copy/paste for someone else to read.

Comment: Did you already specify the password in the `GRANT USAGE` statement?